# How to restrict area of drag&drop ImageView Android

Tags: android, android-layout, drag-and-drop

How to limit area of moving `ImageView` so it doesn't go out of `RelativeLayout` area.

My code for moving `ImageView` is:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {
    if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        oldXvalue = me.getX();
        oldYvalue = me.getY();

    } else if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight());
        params.leftMargin = (int) (me.getRawX() - (v.getWidth() / 2));
        params.topMargin = (int) (me.getRawY() - (v.getHeight()));
        v.setLayoutParams(params);

    }
    return true;
}
```

I was looking already for answer on StackOverflow but didn't find it.

Comment: Instead of making screenshot, copy and paste your code in question...

Comment: Sorry first time on stackoverflow :)

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow! I improved your question. Look in edit history what I did and how you should do next time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        if(params.leftMargin<=0){
            params.leftMargin=0;
        }
        if(params.topMargin<=0){
            params.topMargin=0;
        }

        if(params.leftMargin>=width-(v.getWidth())){
            params.leftMargin=(int)width-(v.getWidth());
        }

        if(params.topMargin>height-(v.getHeight())){
            params.topMargin=(int)height-(v.getHeight());
        }


        v.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Solved it! :)